# Windows Failed to Start - 0xc0000098 (on Install Win 10 Pro from USB 3.0)

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-installation

My old laptop hard drive crashed,  I put in a new one and bought Windows 10 Pro on USB stick.  It boots, and after I pick 64-bit, it says it's loading files, then it ends with the error 0xc0000098 - The operating system couldn't be loaded becasue a critical system driver or missing or contains errors.  It shows File: \windows\System32\drivers\volmgrx.sys.

If instead I pick 32-bit, it says file: \windows\system32\boot\winload.efi and Status: 0xc0000359 - the application or operation system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

Screen shots of each of three steps: 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When exactly do these errors arrive: Windows boot, or earlier during the installation (and at what step).

Comment: I gave all the steps above.

Comment: The 32-bit boot cannot succeed because apparently you have a UEFI firmware that can only work with 64-bit. The other error may show a problem with your new hard disk. Which make is it?

Comment: It's an HGST 1TB Serial ATA/300 (I think it's Western Digital).  Do I need to run FDisk on it? If so, would I need to do that on another computer?   The File in the errors doesn't specify drive, so is it the boot drive itself?

Comment: I could see that maybe the disk needs to be partitioned, initialized, formatted or whatever, but how do you do that without Windows on that machine?  Can I put it in a USB and do it on another computer?

Comment: I am trying to format drive now on another computer...

Comment: Put disk back in - same error: 0xc0000098 - The operating system couldn't be loaded becasue a critical system driver or missing or contains errors. It shows File: \windows\System32\drivers\volmgrx.sys.

Comment: From the look of it...is it possible that you didn't buy a Windows 10 installation flash drive, but a flash drive with Windows 10 already on it? It sure looks like you want to boot windows off a USB stick that hasn't been configured for your PC. You need to buy an Installation disk or USB flash drive to install windows on your Hard Drive.

Answer (score 2):

All the errors you are getting relate to a mismatch between the BIOS/UEFI
and the Windows version that you are trying to install.

You have probably changed some settings in the BIOS/UEFI that make it incapable
of installing neither 32-bit nor 64-bit Windows.

To install Windows to an EFI-based computer, you must enable EFI mode in the
computer’s firmware and boot with 64-bit media.

If you don't know what you changed in the BIOS/UEFI, I suggest to reset it to
default values, then examine it well in order to see whether it is UEFI or
BIOS, and if UEFI then ensure it is really set to boot in UEFI mode.

Comment: From the third screen shot, in lower right (not very clear in photo) it says Esc=UEFI.  When I click that, I can press F2 to see the BIO.  Boot Mode is set to UEFI, external Device Boot is Enabled.  Boot Priority has Exsternal Device first. From BIOS, I pressed F9 (Setup Defaults), confirmed "Yes" to Load default configurations now?", and Boot Mode is still UEFI, but external device boot is disabled, and Boot Priority has internal hard drive first.

Comment: I bought Windows 10 Pro on USB stick.  It says on box "32 and 64-bit on USB 3.0 included"

Comment: I'm working out of town, so won't be able to return to this project until week before Christmas.

Comment: Did you try to install with these settings? Where did you buy Windows 10?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "these settings". Settings used as above are: Boot Mode is set to UEFI, external Device Boot is Enabled. Boot Priority has Exsternal Device first.  Bought it at Frye's.

Comment: Any other ideas? I'll be home this weekend, and would like to try again before I trash the computer.

Comment: Try to reset the BIOS. Question: What is the computer model?

Comment: Sony Vaio Model:SVE171E13L

Comment: Reset BIOS, the changed to boot from external.  Same as reported in original question.

Comment: I cannot find that model on the Sony site. What Windows version it came with originally?

Comment: It was either Win 7 or Win 10 (Home).  I bought Professional for the re-install because there were somethings you could do with Docker and virtualization layer.

Comment: There might be a sticker on the computer with that info. I would think it was Windows 7, and it might be worthwhile to install the original Windows version (even without activation). All Windows versions can be [upgraded to Windows 10 Pro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/windows-10-upgrade-paths).

Comment: Yes, the sticker says Windows 8 (forgot about that version).  What difference would that make? Some kind of hardware incompatability with Windows 10 you think? Approx mfg date 2013-01.

Comment: It would be useful to see if Windows 8 can install correctly, where Windows 10 apparently cannot. If you got an installation DVD/USB with the computer, you may use it. Best is if you have not formatted the disk, to see whether you can boot the installation media to Repair mode, for restoring the last-installed Windows version which did work, then do in-place upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue where to find the Windows 8 install.

Comment: Microsoft only supplies downloads for [Windows 8.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO), but the Windows 8 serial might still work. There exist other third-party sources that I would hesitate to recommend.

Comment: Thanks, I just went with Ubuntu.  The laptop didn't have the Windows key on a sticker on the back, so right now, I don't know where I saved all the stuff that came with the laptop.

Comment: Even a Windows 10 installation media might be used to repair and reset the computer, if the original recovery partition is still there.

Comment: I put in a new hard-drive, no change of repair/recovery. I'm not sure I never tried recovery on the old hard drive, maybe some future weekend I might try that.

Answer (score 0):

1. A **pure UEFI x64 Boot media** has to be prepared as said by **harrymc**.
2. > I could see that maybe the disk needs to be partitioned, initialized,
   >   formatted or whatever, but how do you do that without Windows on that
   >   machine?

   It can be directly done from the USB Installation media. Just need to 
   delete all the partitions on the disk ( if Any! ) & make sure that the full 
   disk is an unallocated space.

   OR

   Prepare & boot into **Pure UEFI bootable media** of this [Win 10 x64 Recovery Media](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/322-winpese-x64-14393/) by 
   **KYHI** , use on the same laptop & make the disk unallocated.

   OR

   connect the hard disk to another PC with OS & make it so.
3. **Ideal Settings** : UEFI Boot Mode, External device boot enabled, First Boot Priority : Internal Hard disk. Always use **One Time Boot Menu** Key to boot into external media.
4. You already have one license that came with the Laptop & probably, still tied to its BIOS! You need not install win 8 on it. If you directly start with Win 10 Installation media, you will be automatically upgraded to a win 10 edition you are eligible for. For eg. if the laptop came with Win 8 SL, you will be upgraded to win 10 Home. If win 8 pro, then to win 10 pro.
5. **Compatibility** :

   (i) No incompatibility with win 10 **99%** & if it's there, it can be solved!

   (ii) It is possible that the new hard disk is not compatible with the laptop's hardware : 
   chipset, etc.

   (iii) Other than that a BIOS Update can solve the problem if any!
6. Hard disk is changed so no repair option as said by **User025**
7. If you want to install win 8 on it, It will automatically pick the version as it picks for win 10.
8. The laptops shipped with windows 8, don't come with a key sticker on the back. Its tied to BIOS & will be picked automatically as said above.

Comment: Windows 8 & 10 Installation media can be made for free : https://www.howtogeek.com/186775/how-to-download-windows-7-8-and-8.1-installation-media-legally/

Comment: & You have one more license : Win 10 Pro. If it's genuine!

Comment: I did buy the Windows 10 Pro in a Microsoft box at Frye's store.  I think I did format the disk in a USB case on another machine. Thanks for the info about the BIOS and license, I might try the Windows 8 download then. (I did install Ubuntu on it last weekend.)

Comment: **1.** **I did buy the Windows 10 Pro in a Microsoft box** . Does it mention 25 Digit key ? **xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx**   ( _Don't Share!_ )   **2.** You can directly proceed with win 10 installation media on that laptop. **3.** The win 10 pro key is second win 10 key. Did you get it ?

Comment: **4.** You need to just delete all the partitions on the disk & make it a **single Unallocated space**. ( Better use **Minitool Partition Wizard** or other good **3rd Party app** for that! ) **5.** Formatting, Partitioning etc. will be done by installation itself. **6.** **First Boot Priority** for **Internal Disk** is ideal. If you want to boot into external media, always use **One Time Boot Menu**.

Comment: Don't see any key on the box anywhere.

Comment: The key will have been included within the package somewhere & not on the top of the box, to avoid any issues!

Comment: Windows 10 can be installed without a key .You can activate it later.