# Windows Failed to Start - 0xc0000098 (on Install Win 10 Pro from USB 3.0)

Tags: installation, windows-10

My old laptop (Sony Vaio) hard drive crashed, I put in a new one and bought Windows 10 Pro on USB stick. It boots, and after I pick 64-bit, it says it's loading files, then it ends with the error 0xc0000098 - The operating system couldn't be loaded becasue a critical system driver or missing or contains errors. It shows File: \windows\System32\drivers\volmgrx.sys.

If instead I pick 32-bit, it says file: \windows\system32\boot\winload.efi and Status: 0xc0000359 - the application or operation system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.

Screen shots of each of three steps:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've formatted drive on  another computer. 
It's an HGST 1TB Serial ATA/300 (I think it's Western Digital).

I've tried this in the BIOS: 
From the third screen shot, in lower right (not very clear in photo) it says Esc=UEFI. When I click that, I can press F2 to see the BIO. Boot Mode is set to UEFI, external Device Boot is Enabled. Boot Priority has Exsternal Device first. From BIOS, I pressed F9 (Setup Defaults), confirmed "Yes" to Load default configurations now?", and Boot Mode is still UEFI, but external device boot is disabled, and Boot Priority has internal hard drive first.

Comment: I posted this on ServerFault because i wasn't getting any godo answer previously on SuperUser. https://superuser.com/questions/1378265/windows-failed-to-start-0xc0000098-on-install-win-10-pro-from-usb-3-0 and not enough points on SuperUser to boost.

Comment: Please add the model numbers for laptop and disk.